# Connecting Power Virtual Agent Chatbot to Twilio SMS via Azure Bot

Tags: azure, twilio, botframework, chatbot

I am working with a Power Virtual Agent (PVA) chatbot which I've set up using the PVA UI without any code. My goal is to allow users to interact with this bot via Twilio SMS, i.e., they send a text to the bot, and the bot responds in the same session and can have a contextual conversation because their are deep seeded questions involved in some QnA flows.

**DirectLine Token with Twilio**: I noticed that there's a way to integrate Twilio using a DirectLine token. I suspect this requires setting up the bot programmatically (e.g., with nodejs). I'd like to see if there's a no-code way to achieve this?

I've also connected this PVA bot to Azure Bot and Azure Insights Integration: I've connected the PVA chatbot to an Azure Bot and have set it up with Azure Insights for metrics. Within the Azure Bot, there's a 'Channels' section where I see an option to connect to platforms like Twilio. I've successfully connected Twilio as a channel and I've attempted messaging the bot but it seems it's not linking up with my PVA bot via message endpoints.  I've also tried several webhook url's on Twilio's end as well ('When a message comes in').

My hope is that someone has connected their PVA bot to Twilio SMS whether that involves Azure Bot or another means.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow these steps for connecting a PVA bot to an Azure Bot Service instance, [Add Power Virtual Agents bot to Azure Bot Service channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/publication-connect-bot-to-azure-bot-service-channels)?

I won't rehash all the steps listed in the doc. In short, you need to get the token endpoint from the Twilio Channel in your *PVA* bot's Settings/Channels blade. The token generated from this endpoint is used for connecting your PVA bot via DirectLine to this associated ABS Twilio channel. Additionally, there is necessary code that needs to be included for managing the various client connections and conversations.

Also, be sure you have published your bot in PVA.